# Replace character sequence with several characters using AWK gsub()

Tags: awk

I'm trying to convert text by replacing several identical letters (more than 3)  with several characters (two *).

My input:

```
ffffOOOOuuuurrrr
fffffiiiiivvvvveeeee
```

What should I get:

```
**OOOO****
********
```

My test command is:

```
awk '{gsub(/[a-z]{4}/,"*"); print}' textfile
```

I don't understand how to transform `{4}` into 'more than 3'.

Also how to print `*` two times (like multiply it).

I'm also sure that the condition 'more than three' will convert input into:

```
**OOOO**
**
```

Is there any way to avoid this (replace a sequence of identical letters)?

Or it is not possible to fit in one small command.

Comment: Use `{4,}` to match 4 or more.

Comment: You only want to match repetitions of the same character? `[a-z]{4}` matches any 4 lowercase characters, not the same character 4 times. To do what you want you need back-references, which aren't in standard `awk`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361427/backreference-in-awk-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX awk or sed don't support back-references. You will need to use `gnu-sed` or `perl`:

```
sed -E 's/([a-z])\1{3,}/**/g' file
```

```
**OOOO****
********
```

or using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/([a-z])\1{3,}/**/g' file
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `([a-z])`: Match `[a-z]` and capture in group #1
- `\1`: Back-reference of the letter captured in group #1
- `{3,}`: Repeat 3 or more times

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I tried to use `sed`, but its syntax seemed complicated to me. Option `-E` is stands for back-references? 3 or less will be `{,3}` I guess, but how about from 2 to 4 times.

Comment: As I mentioned it needs gnu sed. For 2 to 4 times, use `s/([a-z])\1{1,3}/**/g` as we have already matched one letter in group.

Comment: Just to be clear, ITYM `don't support back-references **in the regexp**`.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned `sed` as an option in the tags:

```
echo "fffffiiiiivvvvveeeee" | sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\1\1\1\+/\1/g'
five
echo "fffffiiiiivvveeeee" | sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\)\1\1\1\+/\1/g'
fivvve
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with any awk assuming a locale where lower case letters are a-z = ASCII 97-122:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (i=97; i<122; i++) {
        gsub(sprintf("%c{3,}",i),"**")
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
**OOOO****
********
```

otherwise with GNU awk for the ord() function:

```
$ cat tst.awk
@load "ordchr"
{
    for (i=ord("a"); i<=ord("z"); i++) {
        gsub(sprintf("%c{3,}",i),"**")
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
**OOOO****
********
```

or iyou can use a different numeric loop range or `split("abc...z",...)` or whatever else to get the loop but the point is - you need to loop on each character.